# React - Map through array of objects to create Date TextFields in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I've got an array of objects that denote different steps in a certain process, where each step has an id and name. The array of objects looks something like this:

```
const steps = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: start
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: middle
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: end
  }
]
```

In one of my files, I am mapping through this array of objects to create a `TextField` of type `date` with Material UI. This looks like:

```
{
  {steps.map((step, index) => {
    return (
      <TextField
        id={step.id}
        label={step.name}
        type={"date"}
        value={step.name}
      />
    )
  })}
}
```

My question is now two-fold:

1. **What is the best way to create a state for each of the steps so that I can create an `onChange` event in the TextField component and store each of the dates in their respective states?**

Right now, I've declared the state to pretty much mimic the array of objects, although, I'm not sure this is the best way because it can sort of get out of hand the more steps are added:

```
const [stepDates, setStepDates] = useState({
  start: null,
  middle: null,
  end: null
})
```

2. **If I do declare the states to be as above, how do I actually set the value of each state in the `onChange` event?**

I've done it like this so far:

```
<TextField
  id={step.id}
  label={step.name}
  type={"date"}
  value={step.name}
  onChange={event => {
    const val = event.target.value
    setStepDates(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, step.start: val } 
    })
  }
/>
```

However, with the above, I get an error around `step.start` saying:

> Parsing error: ',' expected

Comment: your parsing error was due to the invalid label usage, `step.start: val` is invalid as long as it is not wrapped in a brackets `[step.start]: val`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, to fix your problem you can dynamically reference a key:

```
<TextField
  key={step.id}
  id={step.id}
  label={step.name}
  type="date"
  value={step.name}
  onChange={event => {
    const val = event.target.value
    setStepDates(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [step.name]: val }))
  }
/>
```

You don't really need to initialize each state item, you could just assume null/undefined if it's not present:

```
const [stepDates, setStepDates] = useState({})

stepDates.middle // it returns undefined
```

Comment: an `id` would be better as this must be unique :)