# React - Map through array of objects to edit Date TextFields in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

I've asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68361330/react-map-through-array-of-objects-to-create-date-textfields-in-material-ui) of mine where I asked how it may be possible to set a value over a mapped array of objects. However, I'd now like to now figure out how it may be possible to edit the values if they exist.

For example, suppose I have an array of objects:

```
const steps = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: start
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: middle
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: end
  }
]
```

In one of my files, I am mapping through this array of objects to create a TextField of type date with Material UI. This looks like:

```
{steps.map((step, index) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      id={step.id}
      label={step.name}
      type={"date"}
      onChange={event => handleStepDateChange(event.target.value, step.name)}
    />
  )
})}
```

I have defined a separate state to check which dates the user has selected (as they can leave one more more of the steps' dates blank). The initial state declaration is just an empty array as follows.

```
const [datesOfSteps, setDatesOfSteps] = useState([])
```

As a result, I have implemented an `onChange` handler that will add each of the selected dates to an array of objects. The onChange handler that is called from above looks like this:

```
cost handleStepDateChange = (dateSelected, stepName) => {
  setDatesOfSteps([
    ...datesOfSteps,
    {
      date: dateSelected,
      name: stepName
    }
}
```

In essence, every time the user selects a date for a step, a new entry is inputted in the array. This all works fine to store the dates in the array.

**My question is:** Suppose now, however, I have somewhere on my site a way for the user to "edit" the dates once they've saved. I would like for the user to be able to see which dates they have previously selected. For this, I need to be able to have a `value` prop in the `TextField` component so that I can set each of the values in the dates to be what was previously saved (this is stored and retrieved from a backend).

**How can I go about setting a value prop in the original mapping?** How can I put a variable in the `value` prop?

```
{steps.map((step, index) => {
    return (
      <TextField
        id={step.id}
        label={step.name}
        type={"date"}
        //value={WHAT DO I INCLUDE HERE}
        onChange={event => handleStepDateChange(event.target.value, step.name)}
      />
    )
  })}
```

I hope this is clear, please let me know if it's not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution is to filter() based off the name, something like:

```
{datesOfSteps.filter((dateStep) => {
  if (dateStep.name = step.name) {
    return dateStep.date
  }
}
}
```

to find the correct date value from the step.name value, but I wouldn't recommend that solution.

Isn't it better to include make "steps" a state value that also includes the date, rather than storing the date value associated with each step in a separate array? It will re-render when values are changed, but so will any controlled input field.

Comment: Thank you for your input. To your second point, the only reason I haven't made steps a state value simply because if the number of steps gets large, I'll have to continue adding objects to the state array, which I'm not too fond of doing. Right now, the step constants is in a different file so it's manageable and it doesn't clutter my component.

Comment: I will give your potential solution a try.

Comment: I was suggesting that filter be in the value prop, yea, but it introduces plenty of issues, such as that one. A hacky solution would be to use an || operator.

You could also give them local state values, but then do the filter to edit on submission, or add them to the dateOfSteps array if there is no existing value for that name.

The easiest solution is to to simply filter what "steps" show up on the edit page, and only include them if they have an existing value in dateOfSteps (you can use a similar filter, just on the map rather than on the value field)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The only problem with your last point is that I would like the user to not only edit (i.e. modify dates that they've previously entered) but also be able to amend dates they may have left off (i.e. add new ones to other steps).

Comment: In that case, you could initialize setDatesOfSteps using the data from steps, with empty quotes for the date value?

Comment: Good idea. I'll give that a try. I have tried to implement the way using filters (as per your original answer), but I don't think the `value` prop is correct as even though it technically allows me to select a date (I can see this through a console log), it doesn't appear on the UI.